# Not exiting from python socket program

Tags: python, sockets

I have the following python UDP socket client. I want to exit from the program when pressing crtl+ c, but it is not happening due to the the thread,how can I solve this ?

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
import signal
import sys
message = "well"
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 3447)
def sighandler(signum, frame):
    # Close the server
    global sock
    print 'Shutting down server...'
    # Close existing client socket   
    sock.close()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sighandler)

def recv():
    while True:
        print "Waiting to receive data"
        data, server = sock.recvfrom(4096)
        print "Server : ", server
        print "data   : ", data
Thread(target=recv).start()

try:
    while True:
        message = raw_input()
        print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % message
        sent = sock.sendto(message, server_address)
except:
    import traceback; traceback.print_exc();

finally:
    sock.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes all you need in threading is:

```
t = Thread(target=recv)
# Daemon runs in background, and main can respond to ctrl-c.
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```